# Pattern for building object collection with interdependencie

Tags: design-patterns, instantiation

On multiple projects in which I was involved, I faced the same situation : build object family from XML data or from database.

For instance, we can consider e-commerce entities :

- Model entities : Product, Category, Price, Customization, ... (each entity identified by ID).
- Some 'complex' relationships between entities :

  - Product has a Category, a Price, a list of Customization, a list of recommended products
  - Category can have a Parent Category
  - ...

Now we want to load the object representation of the XML data. Depending on XML schema, it happens that the entity we are building has a relation toward another entity which is not yet created.

Facing this scenario, I always end up with this kind of strategy :

- Having a Dictionary for each entity type, So I can reach an object knowing his ID,
- For each relationship, having a List> that represents "This object has a missing relationship, you will have to resolve it later with the object having this ID"

So, when building an object :

- if a property is an ID refering to another object, I look into the corresponding Dictionary with this ID. If found, the property is set. If not found, I store in
- I add this object reference into the Dictionary (however the object is complete or not), and continue with following object

When all objects are built, there are still missing relation. So I iterate over my lists and resolve .

I always found this quite ugly :

- A lot of code (which is not really understandable for my team),
- a lot of Dictionary and List,
- probably poor performances

Is there any common/good pattern for this situation ? Any way that creational patterns or IOC could help me (Can't really see how) ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to the problem:

1) maintaining a tree of objects (strict aggregation or containment) 
2) maintaining a network of objects.

If you use a technology such as JAXB to construct a tree from an XML file, solving (1), you need only make a couple of additional passes to a) build up the dictionary and b) resolve references to solve (2).

The advantage to this approach is that JAXB is a well-maintained technology, and, arguably, well-documented. With 80% of the problem in hand, you can then craft some documentation for the second part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Builder for this. With Builder, you have a protocol for constructing something that you are trying to keep separate from the details of its specific construction elements, so you would have an XML builder and a database Builder.

The problem with this is that Builder is really designed for things that are built in stages. Your description does have some notion of stages, but its mainly just the usual leaf/node logic of construction.

Which of course, implies Composite (Builder is often used with Composite). No doubt that could play here.

The main thing I would advise is to avoid the dream of total abstraction. For years seemed like everyone wanted to be able to just hand over arbitrarily complex graphs to something that would serialize and deserialize them in XML. That's a stupid dream, and as the Apache Axis project can testify, one that can eat you alive.

If you look at the way this problem is tackled in Cocoa (the best all around framework ever AFAIC), there is a protocol (interface) called NSCoding. Each entity you want to persist implements that. There are two methods: encode/decode. The key is that you are simply saying 'here's what I need stored, here's how I can reconstruct myself.' But the true beauty of this approach is that you are keeping the actual format completely separate, and that only ever gets done once! So supposed you want to encode an object graph in JSON. You write a JSON encoder and decoder once, then a year in the future, someone can come into the project and add to the object graph and make their new stuff serializable without ever even seeing a lick of JSON code (or writing any).